# Using positive lookahead in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm writing a regular expression for the following phrase variations:

- "cart total is greater than $5.00"
- "cart total is less than $5.00"
- "cart total is greater than 5.00" (notice no $ in the number... this is what's failing)

I'm capturing two things: the word "greater" or "less" and the amount. I want to capture the amount whether there's a dollar sign in it or not, but this is what's tripping me up.

Here's my regexp:

```
/^.*(?=cart total).*(?=(greater|less)).*(?=\$([0-9.]+))/
```

This:

```
"cart total is greater than $5.00".match(/^.*(?=cart total).*(?=(greater|less)).*(?=\$([0-9.]+))/)
```

gets me "greater" and 5.00 but this:

```
    "cart total is greater than 5.00".match(/^.*(?=cart total).*(?=(greater|less)).*(?=\$([0-9.]+))/)
```

get me "greater" and ""

I realize the lookahead is searching specifcally for the "$" in the group so taking it out causes it not to find the amount, but I'd love to see how to modify this to find the amount regardless of the presence of "$" or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lookahead is not necessary in this case. I improved your dollar matching slightly to also match with commas in the number, e.g., `$1,000.00`, and without any commas / decimal points, e.g., `$10`.

```
regex = /cart total is (greater|less) than \$?((?:\d+,?)+(?:.\d+)?)/

strings = [
  "cart total is greater than 5.00",
  "cart total is less than $1,500,000.00",
  "cart total is greater than $5"
]

strings.each do |string|
  p string.match(regex)
end

#<MatchData "cart total is greater than 5.00" 1:"greater" 2:"5.00">
#<MatchData "cart total is less than $1,500,000.00" 1:"less" 2:"1,500,000.00">
#<MatchData "cart total is greater than $5" 1:"greater" 2:"5">
```

Comment: This works perfectly and I appreciate the additions to handle commas.

Answer (score 5):

To me lookahead is unnecessary in this case. I have removed those. And added `\$?` for optional dollar sign.

```
^.*?cart total.*?(greater|less).*?\$?([0-9.]+)
```

Comment: This works great! I ended up accepting the answer that slightly improves on the regex by handling commas in numbers, as that is a possibility when dealing with money.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [optional quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`.
A small modification to your original regex-

```
^.*(?=cart total).*(?=(greater|less)).*(?=\$?([0-9.]+))
                                            ^ Added ?
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/iV3cB9)

Comment: The `?` is correct, but -1 for not pointing out the inappropriate use of lookaheads.

Comment: @Alan, +1 to you, not neceessarily for the downvote, but for saying you gave it and giving the reason.  I would like to see that behavior as the norm.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. If you look at your demo you'll notice that the 2nd match is 0 in those examples.